# How to do pattern matching for let expression in racket?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, pattern-matching, racket

Let's say I have the following code:

```
(let ([a 3]
      [b 4])
  (+ a b))
```

To match this expression I try:

```
(match exp
  (`(let ([,id ,val] ...) body)  <code for handling this>)
```

I was hoping `id` will match to `a` and `val` will match to `3`

But `id` matches to `(a b)`, and `val` matches to `(3 4)` instead.

Is there any way I can achieve the first scenario ?

Comment: Since you have the `...`, `id` and `val` can match more than one expression. Therefore, they are wrapped in lists. Consider: if `id` were `a` and `val` were `3`, where would values for the second binding pair (the `[b 4]` part) go?

Answer (score 0):

From the syntax - it looks like you want to use an Indiana style pattern matcher.
There is a port to Racket here. Save "imatch.rkt" in the same folder as your file and then use `(require "imatch.rkt")`.

```
https://github.com/soegaard/indiana
```

Documentation:  http://www.cs.indiana.edu/chezscheme/match/

The alternative is to use the old-style pattern syntax in Racket.

Use `(require mzlib/match)` to get the old syntax.
The documentation is here:  http://docs.racket-lang.org/mzlib/mzlib_match.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. I do notice racket has "match-let". Is there any difference between different match styles? or is it just a matter of taste?

Comment: The idea of the Indiana style (and the old mzscheme) style is that patterns use the same syntax as used to manipulate lists (quote, quasiquote and unquote). This makes the syntax easy to learn. The downside is that it is harder to work with non-list based data structures (e.g. structures). The new Racket style is to use constructor-style in the patterns.